# How to create ENUM type in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, types, enums

I need to convert a table from MySQL to SQLite, but I can't figure out how to convert an enum field, because I can't find `ENUM` type in SQLite.

The aforementioned field is `pType` in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `prices` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `pType` ENUM('M','R','H') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M',
    `pField` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pFieldExt` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cmp_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

I need a field with only three values for the user to chose, and I would like to enforce that in the DB, not just in my application.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

There is no enum type in SQLite, only the following:

- NULL
- INTEGER
- REAL
- TEXT
- BLOB

Source: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

I'm afraid a small, custom enum table will be required in your case.

Comment: Actually "a custom enum table" is a much cleaner design that using real enums

Comment: Why not use CHECK() constraint to allow only three possible strings?

Comment: @Wideshanks I don't think `CHECK()` existed at the time I wrote that answer. Unless the string is *really* short, I'm totally against it. 1 or 2 characters maximum.

Comment: I can use `VARCHAR` in my SQLite version, is that a new type addition?

Comment: @HammanSamuel It's not new, it's resolved as meaning `TEXT`. On the source page I gave, see point 2.1 on Determination of Column Affinity.

Comment: In this case I would just use a TEXT column instead. A tiny integer takes at least one byte to save and so does a single character as was used here.

Comment: @MPelletier would you elaborate on why you advice so strong against `CHECK()` in this way? (If it is still the case)

Comment: @harlekintiger To add more detail to that answer, it really depends on the performance you seek. If it's no issue at all, yeah, I guess using CHECK() is fine. But for bulk inserts or large inserts, I would see this as a big performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 194):

SQLite way is to use a [CHECK constraint](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#ckconst).

Some examples:

```
CREATE TABLE prices (
 id         INTEGER                                PRIMARY KEY,
 pName      TEXT CHECK( LENGTH(pName) <= 100 )     NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 pType      TEXT CHECK( pType IN ('M','R','H') )   NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M',
 pField     TEXT CHECK( LENGTH(pField) <= 50 )     NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 pFieldExt  TEXT CHECK( LENGTH(pFieldExt) <= 50 )  NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 cmp_id     INTEGER                                NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
)
```

This will limit the `pType` column to just the values `M`, `R`, and `H`, just
like `enum("M", "R", "H")` would do in some other SQL engines.

Comment: Welp, actually this implementation does not fully emulate `enum` because it makes it impossible to sort by the integer index of the values (which is possible with an actual `enum` field). Just, everyone, keep that in mind.

Comment: The storage overhead should be considered a caveat as well. While constraints can be used to insure data integrity, and while an index will make queries fast enough, you are still storing strings - if used extensively, this requires several times more storage than proper enums, depending on string lengths. You might need to consider using additional lookup tables and foreign keys to work around this issue.

Comment: Problem with the check is that the values are "magic strings". You cannot reference them somewhere else. I.e. pull them in your code base and use them.

Answer (score 74):

To expand on MPelletier’s answer, you can create the tables like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Price (
  PriceId INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  Name    VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL,
  Type    CHAR(1)       NOT NULL DEFAULT ('M') REFERENCES PriceType(Type)
);

CREATE TABLE PriceType (
  Type    CHAR(1)       PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  Seq     INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO PriceType(Type, Seq) VALUES ('M',1);
INSERT INTO PriceType(Type, Seq) VALUES ('R',2);
INSERT INTO PriceType(Type, Seq) VALUES ('H',3);
```

Now the enumeration values are available directly in the Price table as they would be using an ENUM: you don’t need to join to the PriceType table to get the Type values, you only need to use it if you want to determine the sequence of the ENUMs.

Foreign key constraints were introduced in SQLite version 3.6.19.

Comment: `INSERT INTO PriceType(Type, Seq) VALUES ('M',1), ('R',2), ('H',3);` Should get you a syntax error. _"The first form (with the "VALUES" keyword) creates a single new row in an existing table."_: https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html. Break it up avoid that: `INSERT INTO PriceType(Type, Seq) VALUES ('M',1); INSERT INTO PriceType(Type, Seq) VALUES ('R',2); INSERT INTO PriceType(Type, Seq) VALUES ('H',3);`

Comment: There was an answer that was meant to be a comment, but now it's gone. Essentially, since SQLite 3.7.11, several entries can be made with INSERT. The corrected syntax still works too.

Comment: Don't forget to `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` for every session - because fkeys are disabled by default in sqlite3

Comment: If you wnat to avoid forgetting `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` then you can set that up in your .sqliterc file in your home directory.

Comment: Also, you may want to use the `UNIQUE` constraint on Seq.   Something like this `CREATE TABLE PriceType( Type Char(1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Seq INTEGER UNIQUE);`

Comment: Why would you create a separate 'Seq' column instead of just using the default [rowid column](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)?

Comment: The main purpose of the Seq column will be for sorting, I suppose. Therefore I think it will be better to use 10, 20, 30... instead of 1, 2, 3... to be able to insert a new enum later which should appear e.g. between 20 and 30 in sort order.