# Adding constraints to sqlite from sequelize model 'define'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I am using SequelizeJS to create models for my nodejs application. I have my model definitions defined in a startup file and will sequelize.sync() upon application launch.
My question is, I have many constraints in the data that is being added into the fields 
Eg: I have a field called 'source' which is of type Sequelize.ENUM and its values should only be one of these ['pod', 'must', 'cap']. 
In sqlite I have option to put these contraints in the DB directly. How do I do the same from sequelize? can it be done during sync()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sequelize.define('model', {
    source1: Sequelize.ENUM('pod', 'must', 'cap'),
    source2: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM,
        values: ['pod', 'must', 'cap']
    }
```

The code above will create an enum type in sequelize, that is restricted to the values you gave. However, sqlite [does not natively support enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299267/how-to-create-enum-type-in-sqlite), which means the field will just be created as text:

```
..., `status` TEXT, ...
```

BUT, the values will still be validated in javascript, before they are inserted.

In mysql / pg an actual enum, limited to the values will be created:

```
... `status` ENUM('pod', 'must', 'cap'), ...
```

Examples of using the enum type can also be found in the documentation at http://sequelizejs.com/documentation