# What is the best way to store an enum in a database in rusqlite?

Tags: sqlite, rust, struct, enums, rusqlite

If I have a simple struct, one attribute of which contains a simple enum, how can I best store examples of this struct with their enumerations in the rusqlite database? Something like:

```
use rusqlite::{params, Connection, Result};

enum Sex{
    Unknown,
    Male,
    Female,
}

struct Person{
    name: String,
    sex: Sex
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let conn = Connection::open_in_memory()?;

    conn.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE  people(
            name TEXT NOT NULL,
            sex TEXT NOT NULL
        )",
        (), // empty list of parameters.
    )?;


    let person_01 = Person{
        name: String::from("Adam"),
        sex: Sex::Male
    };

    conn.execute(
        "INSERT INTO people (name, sex) VALUES (?1, ?2)",
        (&person_01.name, &person_01.sex),
    )?;

    Ok(())
}
```

The problem is that sqlite only allows data of restricted types (NULL, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT), trying to use TEXT here for the enum gives the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Sex: ToSql` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:33:9
    |
31  |     conn.execute(
    |          ------- required by a bound introduced by this call
32  |         "INSERT INTO tasklist (name, sex) VALUES (?1, ?2)",
33  |         (&person_01.name, &person_01.sex),
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ToSql` is not implemented for `Sex`
```

This error makes sense, but what is the best way to implement this? Cast the enum to int? I read [here](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/503#issuecomment-277438660) that this is "removes the guarantee that values always represent the variants of the enum", which I agree with. It would be nicer to match the string.

I have tried to do this using [strum](https://crates.io/crates/strum), which allows me to add `to_str` & `from_str` to the enum, allowing it to be added to the database like so:

```
#[derive(strum_macros::Display, strum_macros::EnumString, Debug)]
enum Sex{
    Unknown,
    Male,
    Female,
}

...

    conn.execute(
        "INSERT INTO people (name, sex) VALUES (?1, ?2)",
        (&person_01.name, &person_01.sex.to_string())
    )?;
```

and retrieved like so:

```
    let mut stmt = conn.prepare("SELECT name, sex FROM people")?;
    let person_itr = stmt.query_map([], |row|{
        Ok(
            Person{
                name: row.get(0)?,
                sex: Sex::from_str(String::as_str(&row.get(1)?)).unwrap(),
            }
        )
    });
```

but this feels messy. **Is there a better way?**

I have seen [here](https://gist.github.com/dbrgn/9e88f54e23b4640bb3641734277a85dd) people manually implementing `FromSqlRow` for the enum, but is there a better (quicker) way?

Comment: The most common approach seesm to be, to implement ToSql for the enum and map it to a TEXT. This way you can use the most the approach described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299267/how-to-create-enum-type-in-sqlite

Comment: `Sex::from_str(String::as_str(&row.get(1)?))`

Comment: @cdhowie, with a slight modification I was able to get this to work: 
`Sex::from_str(String::as_str(&row.get(1)?)).unwrap()`. But it is somewhat messy. I will modify the question to reflect this. Thank you.

Comment: @FinleyGibson You probably want `?` (or maybe `.map_err(...)?`) instead of `.unwrap()` so you don't panic out of the whole program if there is bad data in the DB. Having said that, implementing `ToSql` and `FromSql` on your type is the right way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to handle this is to implement `ToSql` and `FromSql` directly on your enum.  This will make using it substantially more ergonomic, and possibly more efficient since you don't first have to convert to a type with an allocation, like `String`.

It also means the conversion to/from a string doesn't "infect" every interaction you have with the database; the conversion becomes automatic.  So, while there is a bit more boilerplate, it will pay off every time you use this type in conjunction with the database.

```
impl ToSql for Sex {
    fn to_sql(&self) -> rusqlite::Result<ToSqlOutput<'_>> {
        Ok(self.to_string().into())
    }
}

impl FromSql for Sex {
    fn column_result(value: ValueRef<'_>) -> FromSqlResult<Self> {
        value.as_str()?.parse()
            .map_err(|e| FromSqlError::Other(Box::new(e)))
    }
}
```

Now you can just do this when converting to `Person`:

```
sex: row.get(1)?,
```

Note that `FromSqlRow` is a trait specific to a postgres client; rusqlite has no such trait.  If you wanted to, you could create a factory method on `Person` that constructs from a `Row`.  That's up to you.

Comment: this works but seems like a good place for a derive macro, no?